# Fibonacci's proof that $x^3+2x^2+10x=20$ has no solution in radicals?

Tags: polynomials, math-history

I read on a poster today that Fibonacci showed that $x^3+2x^2+10x=20$ has no solution expressible in radicals, way back when.

I couldn't find the proof anywhere. Does anyone know where I can find it?

Comment: That must be wrong; the [Cardano-Tartaglia formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardano_formula#General_formula_for_roots) shows that every cubic equation with integer coefficients has a solution expressible in radicals.

Comment: See http://www.math.vt.edu/people/brown/doc/fibo_number.pdf for a discussion of what Fibonacci did or did not do.

Comment: The key point in the article Barry Cipra linked: “[Fibonacci] proves that [the real root] is neither an integer, nor rational, nor any of the forms from Book X of Euclid's *Elements*.  He continues, ‘And because it was not possible to solve this equation in any of the above ways, I worked to reduce the solution to an approximation.’” The approximation was (in base-60 notation) $1;22,07,42,33,04,40$, or around $1.36880810785322359396$.

Answer (score 1):

Your claim is wrong. Here is the one real root the polynomial has. Define $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{176+3\sqrt{3930}}$. Then the real root is
$$\dfrac13\left(-2 - \dfrac{13 \cdot 2^{2/3}}{\alpha} + \alpha\sqrt[3]2\right)$$

Comment: I believe that the OP meant "with a formula involving only the four basic operations and the extraction of square roots"

Answer (score 1):

He proved that the solution cannot be one of Euclid's irrationals. All Euclid's irrationals are strictly contained in the set of numbers of the form
$$
\sqrt[4]{p}\pm\sqrt[4]{q},
\qquad p,q\in\mathbb{Q}.
$$
The proof would be similar to (but of course more complicated than) how you prove $\sqrt2$ is not rational.